# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when calling sc.textFile("...").take(1)[0]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a file via `textFile()` method. However, when I try `take()` method after it, `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` Exception raises. The file indeed exists.

```
schema_string = sc.textFile(schema_location).take(1)[0]
```

The error message I receive is as follows.

```
File "/home/spark-current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1376, in first
  File "/home/spark-current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1325, in take
  File "/home/spark-current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 389, in getNumPartitions
  File "/home/spark-current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/spark-current/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/home/spark-current/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o136.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createAzureStorageSession(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2812)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2849)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2831)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:322)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 7
```

Comment: Can you please give the file content also?

Comment: It is a json file.

Comment: Then why are you using `textFile`. Use `sc.read.json` I am assuming you are using Azure Databricks.

Comment: So what is the problem with sc.textFile